# How to access local host on Android emulator?

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, android-emulator

SO,
I downloaded Android emulator from visual studio galleries and I installed it successfully. I am trying to access my local host web application with the port 58482 but I wasn't able to access it. I typed 10.0.2.2 on the address bar that didn't help too as many of relevant SO question proposed this. Is there anything missed or is there any other easy way rather than using Mobile emulators to test the mobile development?

Answer (score 1):

Type in the addressbar with the correct **ip address** of your machine like

```
<ip_address>:58482
```

First check it on your computer browser. If its not working then the problem may  with your web application.

Comment: Does it need to be the Ethernet Adapter IP or Wireless IP? I am currently giving the wireless adapter IP and returns a bad request error

Comment: So you did not try all ip's. Any reason you did not?

Comment: Try all ip's. Its not a hard work ahh. It will depend on your connection. Connection from wifi or network cable or any other.